# how to save or get data in object format in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When i am doing a get request to get the user model, I am getting array of object.

```
[ { followers: [],
 followings: [],
 posts: [],
 _id: 5bb04fccnkj8a813e6,
 firebase_id: 'cBeDoamGaiH3',
 name: 'Sujoy Saha',

 __v: 0 } ]
```

But i want it in the below format.ie. in nested object format.

```
{ followers: [],
followings: [],
posts: [],
_id: 5bb04fccnkj8a813e6,
firebase_id: 'cBeDoamGaiH3',
name: 'Sujoy Saha',

__v: 0 }
```

this is my user schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
firebase_id:{
    type: String,
    required:true
},
name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},

followers:[
    {
        type: String 
    }
],
followings:[
    {
        type: String
    }
]
});
```

What change do i have to made for this?

Comment: just put array[0] you will get object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheme itself is fine. The get request that you are using is probably `find` which returns multiple documents in an array. That's why you see an array wrapping your object. Try using `findById` or `findOne` to get a single document and it will be returned as an `object` instead of `array`